# Created 5th hard partition

Tags: hard-drive

I have an hard disk with 4 primary partitions used to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows, but I have 300 GB of unallocated space.

How can I use it?

Comment: What is you current partition table? What you need to do?

Comment: ntfs - system received-350MB
ntfs 100GB
ntfs 200GB
Unlocated soace 300GB

extended partition 100GB

Comment: its not giving permission to create extended partitions.please tell me how to do that.

Comment: If you already have an extended partition, you must move the unallocated space into the extended to be able to create as many logical partitions as you want. If unallocated not next to extended, then you may have to move partitions around or backup & delete and recreate as a logical. If unallocated next to extended just expand extended.

Comment: You need to resize extended partition and make it larger. If you post a screenshot of gparted, we will explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

Four primary partitions are the maximum:

- The total data storage space of a PC HDD can contain at most four primary partitions, or alternatively three primary partitions and an extended partition.
- An HDD may contain only one extended partition, but that extended partition can be subdivided into multiple logical partitions.

Therefore you will have to delete a partition to create a new partition or you can increase the size of a partition.

The easiest way is, in my opinion with a Live System and Gparted: [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/126153/367165)

Comment: Gparted not allowed to create Extended partitions.Its gray color.

Comment: the easiest way is......

Comment: As I said: with a Live System. Boot a Live System (CD, DVD, Flash) and install `gparted` with `sudo apt-get install gparted`.

Comment: I did that two ways.I created one logical partition and 4 primary partitions.but after i created system not going to open.

Comment: You can't create four primary partitions and an additionally partition. Read my answer. :)

Comment: @A.B. Gparted is always installed to Live.